# TestCafe-- Proper way to assert an element is visible

Tags: testing, automated-tests, assert, visible, testcafe

Based on various forum discussions, the TestCafe documentation, and trying it out to compare results, I am still not certain which is the correct (or best) way to assert that a page element is visible.

`await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').visible).ok();`

vs

`await t.expect(await Selector('#elementId').visible).ok();`

Or are these both incorrect and there is another way that is preferable?  How does this compare to asserting that an element exists?  Or other properties of the element, such as :checked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, both variants are possible. Nevertheless, it is better to use the first one because the second variant may raise errors at the stage of obtaining the [Element State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html):

[Smart Assertion Query Mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism)

> Or other properties of the element, such as :checked

You can obtain the [Element State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html) and use its [checked](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes) option.

Answer (score 1):

```
await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').visible).eql(true);
```

This should help