# TestCafe with Electron: Determine if app is visible on Windows desktop

Tags: testing, automation, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

Our Electron application starts minimized to the Windows tray notification area i.e. not visible on the desktop.

If I attempt to get visibility information through [methods such as this](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/selector-options.html#optionsvisibilitycheck) or as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486699/testcafe-proper-way-to-assert-an-element-is-visible), checking the 'visible' property always returns **true**.

For example, the below always returns **true** whether the app is minimized to the notification area or visible on the desktop:

```
if(await Selector('button', { visibilityCheck: true }).visible)
    console.log("VISIBLE");
  else
    console.log("NOT VISIBLE");
```

As a hail-mary, I have also attempted to check the 'focused' property but that also always returns **true** (at least on the 'body') regardless of the application's visibility on the desktop.

Does anyone know of a reliable method through TestCafe to determine if the application is visible on the Windows desktop?

Thanks
m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using Electron's API. Please refer to the following article to get details: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisvisible .

Here is the test code:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
fixture `Electron page`
    .page ``;

const isDocumentHidden = ClientFunction(() => {
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    return !win.isVisible();
});

test('is hidden', async t => {
    console.log(await isDocumentHidden());
});
```

I checked the code on your project and it works as expected.